# Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory' not found in init_autoloader.php

Tags: php, installation, zend-framework2

I had successfully tested my ZF2 application on my test server. When I published the application to the live server I got the following error:

```
Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.
```

This error disappeared after adding this line to my index.php.

```
putenv("ZF2_PATH=/opt/zf2/library/");
```

But now I get the AutoloaderFactory-not-found error instead, which means PHP still doesn't find the classes. The live server is a 1und1 (1and1, 1&1) managed server.

`uname -a` yields `Linux infongd8707 2.6.28.8-20120713a-iscsi-ntacker-3ware-sec8-fmon-igb-dif2-grsec #1 SMP Fri Jul 13 13:37:07 CEST 2012 i686 GNU/Linux`

The workaround as described in the [ZF2 installation instructions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/ref/installation.html) doesn't help.

- I'm not allowed to set an environment path in the `httpd.conf`.
- `SetEnv` statements in the `.htaccess` seem to be ignored by Apache's configuration.
- Setting ZF2_PATH with `putenv` does help just a bit as described above.
- Including the library path with `set_include_path`, tried both absolutely and relatively, doesn't help, although `phpinfo()` shows that it's set as local value.

Anybody experienced the same?

Comment: may seem obvious but are you sure the `/path/to/library` is correct?

Comment: The path was just for readability. It's correct in my environment. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I know it was for readability, init_autoloader is failing to `include $zf2Path . '/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';`, which suggests either the `$zf2Path` you gave it is wrong, or perhaps the server doesn't have correct permissions to read it. If you're sure the path is correct, check permissions, and dial up error reporting

Comment: Changed the library path to something more plausible. Thanks [Crisp](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1112089/crisp) for taking your time. The solution is rather simple and surprising. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is rather interesting for 1&1 customers. [It seems](https://www.akeebabackup.com/support/joomlapack-support-11x/general-support/1455-warning-to-11-internet-inc-clients-linux-only.html) as if on their managed servers `unzip`, which I used to extract my project, is an alias for `unzip -L` which forces all extracted files to be lowercase. Since our test server and the live server both are case-sensitive regarding files and directories, this behaviour made lots of directories inaccessible.