# Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am new to Zend framework, when I try to run my skeleton application I am getting following error

> Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\examplezend\init_autoloader.php on line 42

I have googled for the solution but I can't find it.

What may cause this error? Any help will be appreciated.

Pls see below

```
<?php

// Composer autoloading
if (file_exists('vendor/autoload.php')) {
    $loader = include 'vendor/autoload.php';
}

$zf2Path = false;

if (is_dir('vendor/ZF2/library')) {
    $zf2Path = 'vendor/ZF2/library';
} elseif (getenv('ZF2_PATH')) {      // Support for ZF2_PATH environment variable or     git submodule
    $zf2Path = getenv('ZF2_PATH');
} elseif (get_cfg_var('zf2_path')) { // Support for zf2_path directive value
    $zf2Path = get_cfg_var('zf2_path');
}

if ($zf2Path) {
    if (isset($loader)) {
        $loader->add('Zend', $zf2Path);


    } else {

        include $zf2Path . '/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';
        Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory(array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'autoregister_zf' => true
            )
        ));
    }
}

if (!class_exists('Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory')) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or     define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.');
}
```

Comment: Did you check your library include path?

Comment: This might help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643585/fatal-error-class-zend-loader-autoloaderfactory-not-found-in-init-autoloader

Answer (score 0):

Check this line(this line may be in index.php or init_autoloader.php), whether you have mentiond your library path properly or not ( **$zf2Path** ):

```
 include $zf2Path . '/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';
```

EDIT:

Check these lines in init_autoloader.php:

```
if (file_exists('vendor/autoload.php')) {
    $loader = include 'vendor/autoload.php';
}

$zf2Path = false;

if (is_dir('vendor/ZF2/library')) {
    $zf2Path = 'vendor/ZF2/library';
} elseif (getenv('ZF2_PATH')) {      // Support for ZF2_PATH environment variable or git submodule
    $zf2Path = getenv('ZF2_PATH');
} elseif (get_cfg_var('zf2_path')) { // Support for zf2_path directive value
    $zf2Path = get_cfg_var('zf2_path');
}
```

Comment: in init_autoloader.php I have the line, this is the line the error is pointing.

Comment: Check your library path: $zf2Path = 'vendor/ZF2/library';

Comment: I have given my total file in my question, pls see once.

Comment: Where do you kept your library? and echo $zf2Path  before this line: if ($zf2Path) {

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43422/discussion-between-ngm-akumar-and-vamsi)

Comment: I could not chat now. We can do after 2 hrs. is it Ok?